# The Package Version Create Request Id: ... isn't defined in the sfdx-project.json

Tags: salesforcedx, json, unlocked-package, developer-edition

NOTE:org-dependent

I am creating an org-dependent unlocked package with the following:

```
sfdx force:package:create --name TestApp1 --description "TestApp1" --packagetype Unlocked --path force-app --nonamespace --orgdependent --targetdevhubusername DevHub
```

I am not using a scratch org. I get the command:
sfdx-project.json has been updated.
Successfully created a package. 0Ho12300000TN4YXYZ

How do I get the install url for this?
I tried :
sfdx force:package:version:create:report -i 0Ho12300000TN4YXYZ

I get the error:

> The Package Version Create Request Id: 0Ho12300000TN4YXYZ isn't
> defined in the sfdx-project.json. Add it to the packageDirectories
> section and add the alias to packageAliases with its 08c ID.

My sfdx-project.json

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "package": "TestApp",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "default": true
        },
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "package": "TestApp1",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "default": false
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "TestApp",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "50.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "TestApp": "0Ho12340000TN3kXYZ",
        "TestApp1": "0Ho12300000TN4YXYZ"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages are containers, so to speak, for package *versions*. Package versions are what you install. Their ids start with 04t, rather than the 0Ho of the containing package.

You haven't uploaded a package version yet. You need to do so using the `force:package:version:create` command, which you can status-check using `force:package:version:create:report`. Once you have an 04t package version Id, you can install it in an org with `force:package:install --package <04t id>`.

Comment: Thanks David this resolved my issue.